# A weird error occurs on my xml-file during eclipse start and goes away after maven update

Tags: eclipse, oracle, maven

I have a weird error that occurs on my camel-config.xml file that occurs on my datasource pooling. When I start my eclipse, the error shows up that says "Processing XML Error. Resource must not be null", and goes away after I do maven update. I wanted to know what's causing the error to occur in the first place and why does it go away after I update it. Its oracle datapooling and not even related to logic of a particular project. Any thoughts, suggestions or views about this problem are appreciated.

I'm getting error on this piece of code.

```
 <orcl:pooling-datasource id="dataSource1"
    url="${oracle.db1.url}" username="${oracle.db1.username}" password="${oracle.db1.password}"/>
<orcl:pooling-datasource id="dataSource2"
    url="${oracle.db2.url}" username="${oracle.db2.username}" password="${oracle.db2.password}"/>
<orcl:pooling-datasourc
e id="dataSource3"
    url="${oracle.db3.url}" username="${oracle.db3.username}" password="${oracle.db3.password}"/>
```

Thanks,
Gautham

Comment: Is this code being executed on eclipse initialization? And you can go to the error log view for more details.

Comment: This error occurs during two scenarios: One during eclipse start, another when I do maven clean

Comment: Okay yeah, eclipse does some initialization on startup. I would 1. remove this from the startup or 2. (don't recommend this) put null checks.

Comment: Look at the `eclipse.ini` file for startup info

Comment: @GauthamHonnavara Did you ever manage to resolve this?